# Using "value-of-select" to pick the second attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, ffprobe

EDIT to include additional information.

I am using Telestream Vantage to transform an XML into what Telestream refer to as a Metadata Label.

Simple methodology is as follows:

1. Build your Metadata Label Set in the Vantage Management Console
2. Export the Metadata Label Set as an XML
3. From the XML create an XSL which will 'strip' values from a supplied XML and populate the fields of the Label Set.

I have a xml generated by FFProbe which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ffprobe:ffprobe xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:ffprobe='http://www.ffmpeg.org/schema/ffprobe' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.ffmpeg.org/schema/ffprobe ffprobe.xsd'>
<programs>
</programs>

<streams>
    <stream index="1" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="2" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="3" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="4" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="5" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="6" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="7" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="8" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="9" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="10" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="11" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="12" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="13" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="14" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="15" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="16" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="17" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="18" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="19" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="20" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="21" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="22" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="23" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="24" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="25" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="26" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="27" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="28" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="29" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="30" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="31" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="32" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="33" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="34" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="35" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="36" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="37" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="38" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="39" channels="1"/>
    <stream index="40" channels="1"/>
</streams>
```

And I'm trying the extract the 'channels' attribute from each line using the following statement(s):

```
        <soa:Parameter type="int32" identifier="0c000188-c401-4b99-91dc-8e15ebcb7981" bindable="True" name="Stream 01" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
            <xsl:value-of select="default:ffprobe/default:streams[1]/default:stream[1]/@channels"/>
        </soa:Parameter>
```

As you can see, it is the "Value of Select" section that I am looking at.  For each subsequent block I increase the 'stream' reference:

```
<xsl:value-of select="default:ffprobe/default:streams[1]/default:stream[n]/@channels"/>
```

I then run a Vantage Workflow which takes an XML file in as an attachment, and then applies a "Transform" using the Stylesheet and the target Metadata Label Set.

Where I review the metadata label set, all of my values are 0, not 1 as per the imported XML file. My XSL skills are extremely lacking but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*doesn't seem to be working*" is not a good description of a problem. Please post enough code to enable us reproduce the issue, and show us the expected result -- P.S. You need to learn (at least) about the `xsl:for-each` instruction.

Comment: Apologies michael, I have updated the original post to include some additional information.  I don't know if I can use the xsl:for-each instruction, given I have to map each extracted value to a specific parameter within my Vantage XSL.  Does the construction of my xsl:value-of-select at least look correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the W3C tutorials, and some trial and error, the following statement worked:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ffprobe/streams/stream[n]/@channels" />
```

I also changed the ffprobe command string:

```
-print_format xml=fully_qualified=1
```

Which altered the xml that ffprobe outputted to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ffprobe>
    <programs>
    </programs>

    <streams>
        <stream index="1" channels="2"/>
        <stream index="2" channels="4"/>
        ...
    </streams>
</ffprobe>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following xsl statements

```
<xsl:for-each select="/streams/stream">
<xsl:value-of select="/streams/stream/@channels"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="/streams/stream">

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="/streams/stream/@channels"/>

Comment: Not forgetting to close the for-each

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use the <xsl:for-each> tag, as I don't want to to just extract a list of values, but rather within each <soa> block as shown above, map the correct value - each block has it's own GUID.